# Getting Error in JavaScript Calculation (Referring to Previous Calculation)

Tags: javascript, calculation

I am getting an error when trying to calculate a number that uses a number from a previous calculation.

> 1st Calculation: Ending Depth - Starting Depth = Footage.
>
> 2nd Calculation: Footage / Rate of Penetration = Expected Hours to
> Drill.

The second calculation uses footage which is derived from the first calculation.

I have tried numerous ways to do this including adding another event button, but I continue to get an error that seems to be triggered by `else{`

Anyone know what's going on here?

I have a much much longer code, I've isolated this thing down as best as I possibly can.

Tried creating another event button, completely lost here.

```js
function calculate() {
  intervalFootage("Interval-1-StartMD", "Interval-1-EndMD", "Interval-1-Footage");
  expectedHours("Interval-1-ROP", "Interval-1-Footage", "Interval-1-ExpectedHours");
}


function intervalFootage(startingDepth, endingDepth, output) {
  var starting = document.getElementById(startingDepth).value;
  var ending = document.getElementById(endingDepth).value;

  if (starting > -1 && ending > -1) {
    var answer = ending - starting;
  } else {
    var answer = "N/A";
  }
  document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = answer;
}

function expectedHours(rateofpenetration, intervallength, output) {
  var rop = document.getElementById(rateofpenetration).value;
  var length = document.getElementById(intervallength).value;

  if (rop > 0 && length > 0) {
    var hours = length / rop;
  } else {
    var hours = "N/A";
  }
  document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = hours;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Interval 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Staring Depth (MD)</td>
    <th><input type="number" id="Interval-1-StartMD" name="Interval-1- StartMD" min="0"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ending Depth (MD)</td>
    <th><input type="number" id="Interval-1-EndMD" name="Interval-1-EndMD" min="0"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Interval Footage (ft)</td>
    <th id="Interval-1-Footage"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Expected Avg. ROP (ft/hr)</td>
    <th><input type="number" id="Interval-1-ROP" name="Interval-1-ROP" min="0"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Expected Hours to Drill</td>
    <th id="Interval-1-ExpectedHours"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Thanks Calvin, this is my first real attempt to use this forum, trying my best

Comment: ok. Based on what 2nd calc should be, it seems that you never uses the `footage` value there... isn't better to make `intervalFootage()` return the answer value, then when calling `expectedHours()`, pass this answer value to the function?

Comment: also `#Interval-1-Footage` is a `<th>`, and that kind of element doesn't have a `value` property, so in 2nd calc `length` variable will be `undefined`

Comment: Calvin that's what I am trying to do.. but I'm not sure how to actually do that.  Yes, essentially the answer for intervalFootage() needs to be used for expectedHours().  The event button first calculates the footage, but it doesn't seem like it goes any further than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're getting the wrong result because this line
`var length = document.getElementById(intervallength).value;` is actually trying to get the value of a '' element which is `undefined`. If you're trying to get the value you inserted into this td element earlier, you should use `innerHTML` or `innerText` like so:
`var length = document.getElementById(intervallength).innerText;`

Comment: That fixed it.. simple answer thank you and Calvin for your help